# Poll for voting with buttons and percentage fill Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, button, progress-bar, vote

As in the title, I would like to create poll for voting with buttons and percentage fill. As long as someone does not vote, cannot see the results of the poll, only the buttons with the text, after voting, the buttons fill up with color depending on the percentage of votes for each. Additionally, the selected button has a different color than the others. The whole thing can be compared to a horizontal bar chart for voting.

I post only a pictorial photo, the whole thing will have different colors and layout:

[image: example]

Could someone explain to me how to approach something like this and what should I use?